# Framework not found <Library> which I already uninstalled

Tags: swift, xcode

Facing an issue that Xcode says 'framework not found ' when I build.
The weird thing is that I already uninstalled the  by

1. Removed the  from the Podfile
2. `pod update`
3. Reopened `xcworkspace`
   I also tried removing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

- The error I am getting
  [image]
- Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myapp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myapp
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationMaio'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationMoPub'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationUnity'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationVungle'

  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  # For In-app purchase
  pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'

  target 'myappTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'myappUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

## The reason why I want to remove `GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite`.

`GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite` is causing issues below.
[image]

## What I want to ask

- I want to remove `GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite` and build.
- Is there any way to fix the issues that I mention in the reason I want to remove?

Comment: Have you run pod install? Have you opened `xcworkspace` after pod install? Is your pod file actually updated? was pod update successful ? You see where am going with this? Question is very vague, update it with bit more context, which framework, show us pod file, show us exact error to help you better

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Sorry for missing information. I just updated the original post by adding a screenshot of the error I am getting and Podfile. I've tried `pod install` and reopen `xcworkspace`, however, the error still occurs. Though I don't see `GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite` folder in `Pods` dir after `pod update` or `pod install`.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I reinstalled the package and build it. The screenshot I just added shows issues that occurred if I have `GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite`. So I want to either remove the package or fix the error I mentioned in the reason why I want to remove section above.